# UpdateCommand not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

So I have code that stores an UPDATE query in a string, then I parameter bind the update query and then execute and update it, this is my code:

```
string query = "UPDATE Users SET first_name = '@firstname' WHERE ID = @id";
updateUserDS.UpdateParameters.Add("id", HTTPContext.Current.Session["ColumnID"].ToString());
updateUserDS.UpdateParameters.Add("firstname", txt_firstname.Text);
updateUserDS.UpdateCommand = query; 
updateUserDS.Update();
```

However when I change my string query to:

```
string query = "UPDATE Users SET first_name = 'name' WHERE ID = 44";
```

It works perfectly and updates my table, so I am guessing its something to do with how I have binded the query, does anyone realise anything where I have gone wrong?

BTW: The Session["ColumnID"] is being retrieved perfectly as it states 44 in the stack trace

Comment: Take off the single quotes:  `SET first_name = @firstname` - otherwise it will update with the _literal_ string `"@firstname"`

Comment: I'd verify in the debugger that `HTTPContext.Current.Session["ColumnID"]` contains what you'd expect.

Comment: @DStanley Yes, that is what I mean, in the debugger the session contains  what is expected

Comment: Why are you using `SqlDataSource` instead of `SqlConnection` or `OracleConnection` etc?

Comment: @mason Is their a preferred method of doing it?

Comment: @c0mrade Using `SqlCommand` with `SqlConnection` or the equivalent class for your data library is preferred. I created a project on GitHub to demonstrate various data access techniques. [This class](https://github.com/mason-mcglothlin/FancyStoreDemo/blob/master/src/FancyStoreDemo.DataRepositories.MSSQL/MsSqlStoreRepository.cs) in particular should be a good example. Look at the `UpdateProduct` function.

Comment: `SqlDataSource` is really meant to be used as a control, and not programatically (although it's possible to use it programatically). Using the `-Command` and `-Connection` classes directly doesn't depend on `System.Web`, keeping your app size down. You can also reuse connections across database transactions, and perform more specific database things, since `SqlDataSource` is supposed to be semi-DBMS-agnostic.

Comment: @mason Is it not possible to do it using SqlDataSource?

Comment: @c0mrade It's possible, it's just not the best idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the single quotes from `@firstname`:

```
string query = "UPDATE Users SET first_name = @firstname WHERE ID = @id";
updateUserDS.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", first_name);
updateUserDS.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", HTTPContext.Current.Session["ColumnID"].ToString());
```

**EDIT:**

Assuming you are using SQL Server as database try like this:

```
SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand();
sqlComm.CommandText = @"UPDATE Users SET first_name = @firstname WHERE ID = @id";
sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlComm.Parameters["@firstname"].Value = txt_firstname.Text;
sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlComm.Parameters["@id"].Value = HTTPContext.Current.Session["ColumnID"].ToString();    

using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connection string here);)
{
    sqlComm.Connection = sqlConn;
    sqlConn.Open();
    sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: A lot of people are expecting this to work, however it isn't? Am I missing something?

Comment: Okay, just to update you, doing '@firstname' updated it as @firstname so the query is working perfect excluding the quotes, ill give that a try now

Comment: So with the updateUserDS.Parameters it says "SqlDataSource does not contain a definition for Parameters"

Comment: Sorry for not saying but I am using Access

Comment: @c0mrade:- mason has given a solution for MSAccess.

Comment: You **really** should use a `using` statement with your `SqlConnection` since it implements `IDisposable` and uses up network resources.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rewrite this as to use `OldDbCommand` and `OleDbConnection` instead of `SqlDataSource`. It doesn't depend on System.Web assembly (smaller deployment size for non-web situations), there's fewer layers in the stack trace (faster), and it's how most people are used to using ADO.NET.

```
var command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Users SET first_name = ? WHERE ID = ?");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", Session["ColumnID"].ToString());
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("firstname", txt_firstname.Text);

using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    command.Connection = connection;
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

---

Another note, you seem to be doing your database access directly in the UI layer! That's hard to test, and not very flexible. It'd be better if you moved all data access code into a separate class library, and then communicate back and forth by passing *Models*, which are code representations of database entities.

You're also using Access, which isn't really that great of a database system. MS SQL Server is much preferable.

That might look something like this:

Code Behind

```
DataLayer DB {get; set;}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DB = new DataLayer("connectionstring");
}

protected void SubmitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SystemUser user = new SystemUser()
    {
        Id = Session["ColumnID"].ToString(),
        FirstName = txt_firstname.Text
    }
    DB.UpdateUser(user);
}
```

Data Layer

```
public class DataLayer
{
    string ConnectionString {get; set;}

    public DataLayer(string connectionString)
    {
       ConnectionString = connectionString;  
    }

    public void UpdateUser(SystemUser user)
    {
        var command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Users SET first_name = @firstname WHERE ID = @id");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", user.Id);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("firstname", user.FirstName);

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    public void ChangePassword(string UserId, string password)
    {
        //hash and change password here
    }
}
```

Models

```
public class SystemUser
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I would actually prefer using a DataSource. With doing it the way I want it (SqlDataSource) it keeps updating the column to "@firstname" rather than the actual value. Maybe im not bind param'ing it correctly?

Comment: Also, I am passing the code to a separate class just like you said. However I am ammending the query using IF statements and then doing "query = query + "first_name = @firstname"; for example, this is why I prefer using an SqlDataSource

Comment: @c0mrade That doesn't seem like a very good architecture to me. Can you explain why my way of doing it doesn't do what you want?

Comment: Because I have textChanged events which sends to the class whether text has changed and then it ammends the UPDATE query to UPDATE only the fields that have been changed.

Comment: @c0mrade That seems like a waste of time, since it doesn't hurt to update it if it doesn't change.

Comment: Yes but what about the password fields? I don't want the user to be required to update their password just because its not retrievable

Comment: @c0mrade The password would be one of the few exceptions to my above comment, because you should NEVER store the password as plaintext in your database. It should be stored hashed. I'd leave the password column out of the update command, and do all the other columns. Then implement a `ChangePassword` function elsewhere that specifically deals with passwords.

Comment: Okay I totally agree, this was my initial thought however I wanted to update the fields in one form rather than having password in a seperate form. However, from my question, do you not understand what is the problem with the binding?

Comment: @c0mrade You can have it in the same form. I'd actually implement it in a modal dialog window using Bootstrap or jQuery UI. Have a "Change Password" button that displays the dialog window. As for your binding issues, what database are you using? What's the connection string (without password) and provider name?

Comment: Ahhhhh good idea, I won't really need to specify a connection string etc because I'm going to use TableAdapters right?

Comment: @c0mrade I guess you can use Table Adapters, but if you take a look at my example I did it without them. But to know why you're having parameter binding issues, I need to know what database you're using. Different databases have different binding syntaxes.

Comment: @c0mrade And how are you communicating with Access database file? What database provider? `OleDb`?

Comment: @c0mrade I've never used `OleDbConnection` before. [Appears it uses question marks and the order is important](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Are you sure you want to use Access? MS SQL Server would probably be a better fit.